# Unable to install laravel

Tags: php, macos, terminal, laravel-5

I was trying to install Laravel at work and I could not do it, I know there might be a proxy problem because there some restrictions but I am not sure, this is the error message I get when I run the install on terminal

I run this command

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel testproject
```

and I got this error message

```
The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Operation timed out
Retrying with degraded mode, check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#degraded-mode for more info


  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                         
  The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: No route to host
```

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: Most common issue when this error occurs is because you're behind a proxy. You can check if you're behind a proxy by executing `sudo networksetup -getwebproxy` in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I found the slution!
is by adding the proxy at the beginning of the command like this

```
HTTP_PROXY="http;//yourproxy.something" composer create-project
--prefer-dist laravel/laravel testproject
```

est voila, it works :D